# Eval expression with a quoted variables

Tags: r, list, eval

I have multiple expressions( func1, func2..) to evaluate with there parametres for each one :

```
eval(parse(text=func1), list(param1=exp1, param2=exp2, t =trunc),enclos=.GlobalEnv)
```

with :

```
func1 = "rho+lambda"; param1 = "rho"; param2 = "lambda"; exp1 = 0.1; exp2= 0.2
```

indeed, it's work , but when a call the function that contain this eval, a error 
that variable "lambda" not found. 
it's a environnement problem when its a lists. i change the Enclos form parent.frame() to .GlobalEnv.

Any other solution ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the answer is "Don't use `eval(parse())`". There is almost always a much better alternative.

Anyway, you should check the list you pass to it:

```
func1 = "rho+lambda"; param1 = "rho"; param2 = "lambda"; exp1 = 0.1; exp2= 0.2 
eval(parse(text=func1), setNames(list(exp1, exp2), c(param1, param2)))
#[1] 0.3
```